# jQuery search input css sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created Searchbar that scan every user and show them by name, data comes from Laravel to Frontend but there is a problem. When I type name of user it show users that name match to input but it only hide other users and leave empty spaces from them. Maybe is some problem with CSS? Do you have any hints for repair this in jQuery? Please help me.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="show-hide-section">
            <button class="btn btn-success show-hide-search-bar">show searchbar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="searcher-section">
                <div class="show-hide-searcher">
                    <div class="input-section">

                        <div class="label-input-searcher">
                            <label for="" class="searcher-label">Nazwa biura, telefon</label>

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Podaj jeden z parametrów: nazwę biura lub telefon"
                                   class="searcher-input form-control"/>
                            <div class="null-data">Wprowadź poprawną nazwę</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="label-input-searcher">

                            <label for="" class="searcher-label">Lokalizacja</label>

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Podaj lokalizację" class="searcher-input form-control">

                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="searcher-button btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"
                                                                                         aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <div class="select-section">

                        <label for="" class="searcher-label">Rodzaj transakcji</label>

                        <select>
                            <option value="sprzedaż">Sprzedaż</option>
                            <option value="wynajem">Wynajem</option>
                            <option value="oba">Sprzedaż i wynajem</option>
                        </select>

                        <label for="" class="searcher-label">Rodzaj nieruchomości</label>

                        <select>
                            <option value="mieszkanie">Mieszkanie</option>
                            <option value="dom">Dom</option>
                            <option value="lokal">Lokal</option>
                            <option value="grunt">Grunt</option>
                        </select>

                        <label for="" class="searcher-label">Rynek</label>

                        <select>
                            <option value="pierwotny">Pierwotny</option>
                            <option value="wtorny">Wtórny</option>
                            <option value="oba">Pierwotny i Wtórny</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="title" id="agents">Doradcy</h3> {{----}}
    <div class="cards">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4">

        <div class="card" data-firstname="{{$agent->firstname}}" data-lastname="{{$agent->lastname}}" data-email="{{$agent->email}}">
          <figure>
            <div class="img-ref">
              <a href="" class=" ">
                <div style="background: url(' '); background-size: cover; " class="photo "></div>

                <div style="background: url(' '); background-size: cover;" class="photo"></div>

              </a>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" class="teamLink">
                  <h3 class="agent-name"></h3> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="teams-summary">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-position">
              <div class="mobile-info card-contact-info">
              </div>
              <div class="email-info card-contact-info">

              </div>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{----}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".photo").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({"width": "160px", "height": "160px"});
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({"width": "150px", "height": "150px"});
    });
    $(".card").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("cardHover")
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("cardHover")
    });
});





 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show-hide-search-bar').on('click', function () {
            if ($('.searcher-section').is(":visible")) {
                $('.searcher-section').hide("slide");
                $('.show-hide-search-bar').text('Pokaż Wyszukiwarkę');
            } else {
                $('.searcher-section').show("slide");
                $('.show-hide-search-bar').text('Ukryj Wyszukiwarkę');
            }
        });


        $('.searcher-input').keyup(function (event) {
            $('.null-data').hide();
            if ($(this).val()) {
                var input = $(this).val();
                console.log(input);
                $(".card").hide();
                $(".card[data-firstname*='" + input + "']").show();
                if (!$('.card:visible').get(0)) {
                    $('.null-data').show();
                }
            } else {
                $('.null-data').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
     a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card {
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;

}

.cardHover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
}

.photo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.img-ref {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
}

.agent-name {
    height: 25px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-contact-info.mobile-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.card-contact-info.email-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.contact-position {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 5px;
}

/*scroller*/

#scroll {
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px
}

#scroll span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff
}

#scroll:hover {
    background-color: #3498db;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
}

/*SEARCH INPUT LISTA*/

.searcher-section {
    display: block;
}

.searcher-label {
}

.searcher-button {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.select-section {
    float: right;
}

.searcher-input {
    height: 40px;
}

.input-section {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.label-input-searcher {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.show-hide-section {
    margin: 15px;

}

.show-hide-search-bar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. It was problem with bootstrap class "col-xs-12" it has property: min-height: 1px; I just change it in property `$("...").css()`
Here is my solution:

```
       $('.searcher-input').keyup(function (event) {

    $('.null-data').hide();

    var _this = this;

    if ($(this).val()) {
        var input = $(this).val();
        $(".card").hide();
        $(".card[data-firstname*='" + input + "']").show();
        $(".card[data-lastname*='" + input + "']").show();
        $(".card[data-email*='" + input + "']").show();
        $(".col-xs-12").css("min-height", "0");
        $(".col-md-4").css("min-height", "0");
        $(".col-sm-5").css("min-height", "0");
        if (!$('.card:visible').get(0)) {
            $('.null-data').show();
        }
    } else {
        $(".card").show();
        $('.null-data').show();
    }
});
```